# Remove extra spaces in MATLAB strings while ignoring punctuation

Tags: regex, string, matlab, vectorization

Is it possible to ignore punctuation when removing extra spaces in MATLAB strings? I am currently implementing this code:

```
str = " Hello , how are you? ";
output = regexprep(strtrim(str), '\s+', ' ');
```

but output is giving me

```
"Hello , how are you?"
```

rather than

```
"Hello, how are you?"
```

If I use similar strings/char arrays like 'Can I help you  ? ', I get an extra space before the question mark. I believe that isspace and isletter can be used through vectorization, but I am unsure how to nest the function calls.

Comment: Rather than "ignoring" punctuation to find longer runs of spaces, why not just replace all instances of "some number of spaces followed by punctuation" with just the punctuation? You could easily find the matches with regexp

Comment: That makes sense. I was trying to do that, but I couldn't figure out how to remove the multiple spaces between words and punctuation. I'll look into it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To help with your example and trim spaces before punctuation you could use:

```
regexprep(s, ' [,.?!]', '${strtrim($0)}')
```

You may need to expand with additional punctuation characters in the square brackets.

Comment: Great answer, now I just have to work on spaces after punctuation. Thank you!